# How to style each <a> link with a different color on hover?

Tags: html, css

I'm styling a nav bar `<a>` tags and I want each `<a>` tag to have a different color-coded solid border-bottom in line with a logo.

I only want the color border to show on hover. At the moment this is how I have it -

```css
header {
  height: 50px;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

nav a {

  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;

}

nav a:link {

  color: #000000;
  text-decoration-line: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
 <a href="home" style="border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255,29,142);">Home</a>
 <a href="What we do" style="border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(133,52,146);">What we do</a>
 <a href="Who we are" style="border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255,128,55);">Who we are</a>
 <a href="Who we work with" style="border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0,182,223);">Who we work with</a>
 <a href="Say hello" style="border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(63,190,150);">Say hello</a>
 <a href="Blog" style="border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255,222,32);">Blog</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Because each `<a>` tag is a different color I thought this would be the best way to do it but how do I place the rule for it only applying on `a:hover` ?

Comment: See this [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/mk9kb94r/)

Comment: Please don't write answers as a comment. Comments are for clarification and other concerns with the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use inline style then this solution may be help you. Please have a look at the snippet.

```css
header {
  height: 50px;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

nav a {
  position: relative;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

nav a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff; /* same as background color */
}

nav a:hover:after {
  border-color: transparent;
}

nav a:link {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration-line: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="home" style="border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255,29,142);">Home</a>
    <a href="What we do" style="border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(133,52,146);">What we do</a>
    <a href="Who we are" style="border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255,128,55);">Who we are</a>
    <a href="Who we work with" style="border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0,182,223);">Who we work with</a>
    <a href="Say hello" style="border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(63,190,150);">Say hello</a>
    <a href="Blog" style="border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255,222,32);">Blog</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to move those settings to your stylesheet and use more specific selectors: I used `:nth-child(x)` below:

```css
header {
  height: 50px;
}

nav {

  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

nav a {

  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;

}

nav a:link {

  color: #000000;
  text-decoration-line: none;
}
nav a:hover {
border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255,29,142);
}
nav a:nth-child(2):hover {
border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(133,52,146);
}
nav a:nth-child(3):hover {
border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255,128,55);
}
nav a:nth-child(4):hover {
border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0,182,223);
}
nav a:nth-child(5):hover {
border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(63,190,150);
}
nav a:nth-child(6):hover {
border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255,222,32);
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
 <a href="#">Home</a>
 <a href="What we do">What we do</a>
 <a href="Who we are">Who we are</a>
 <a href="Who we work with">Who we work with</a>
 <a href="Say hello">Say hello</a>
 <a href="Blog">Blog</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can maintain the effect you want without using inline CSS.

Using the [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) selector, you can target the exact anchor tag that you want within your navigation.

Apply the color to the border on `:hover`

```css
header {
  height: 50px;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

nav a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

nav a:link {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration-line: none;
}

nav a:nth-of-type(1):hover {
  border-color: rgb(255, 29, 142);
}

nav a:nth-of-type(2):hover {
  border-color: rgb(133, 52, 146);
}

nav a:nth-of-type(3):hover {
  border-color: rgb(255, 128, 55);
}

nav a:nth-of-type(4):hover {
  border-color: rgb(0, 182, 223);
}

nav a:nth-of-type(5):hover {
  border-color: rgb(63, 190, 150);
}

nav a:nth-of-type(6):hover {
  border-color: rgb(255, 222, 32);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="home">Home</a>
    <a href="What we do">What we do</a>
    <a href="Who we are">Who we are</a>
    <a href="Who we work with">Who we work with</a>
    <a href="Say hello">Say hello</a>
    <a href="Blog">Blog</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using nth-of-type selector, otherwise i you really need to define it inline, you can use below code :

```
<a href="http://google.com"
   onMouseOver="this.style.color='#0F0'"
   onMouseOut="this.style.color='#00F'">Google</a>
```